# How do I identify the database a "A system assertion check has failed" error has occured in

Tags: sql-server

Last night I got two alerts about errors from the SQL Server (2019 Enterprise):

One with Severity 020:

> DESCRIPTION:  A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server
> error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a
> software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption,
> consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to
> Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An
> update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or
> in a Hotfix from Technical Support.

Another (at the same timestamp) with severity 016:

> DESCRIPTION:  SQL Server Assertion: File: <"bpjoin.cpp">, line=3448
> Failed Assertion = 'S_OK == hr || DB_S_ENDOFROWSET == hr'. This error
> may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the
> statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural
> integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures
> are not corrupted.

I would like to run the DBCC CHECKDB as suggested, but I can't find anywhere in the error messages or in the SQL Server Error log what database this occured in.
Any suggestions on how to determine the database with the problem (none of them are marked as suspect).

Is it safe to do a reboot of the server, or should I first do the DBCC CHECKDB?

Comment: run the `DBCC CHECKDB` first for all databases.

Comment: Are you on the latest build of SQL Server 2019?

Comment: @Charlieface No, I am on 15.0.4083.2   . I ended up running CHECKDB for all databases as biju jose suggested.

Comment: @Bijujose took your advice and ran for all databases. A lot of large databases on the server, so would have preferred to be able to run for the database in question... if it was possible to find it :)